# jQuery.inArray returns -1 regardless of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm attempting to compare two arrays using the jQuery's .inArray.  This seems straightforward but each value that is compared comes back as -1 (not in the array).  Below is my code

```
finalClick();
function finalClick(){
    roles=["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
    neededRoles=["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
    $(neededRoles).each(function(){
        if(jQuery.inArray(this, roles)=='-1'){
            console.log("not in array "+this);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to play around with it, [you can check out my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/neanderslob/oua4of6g/8/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bergi Strict mode can be avoided in favour of modern methods: `neededRoles.forEach(role) { if( roles.indexOf(role) < 0) console.log("Not in array: "+role); }` ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: It can, but strict mode is a Good Thing(tm). :-)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Wait, you dare not to use jQuery at all?! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `each` method has 2 parameters: `index` and `element`. If you use these parameters instead of `this` your code works

```
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
finalClick();

function finalClick() {
    roles = ["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
    neededRoles = ["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
    // console.log("test: "+roles[0]);
    rolecount = 0;
    console.log("value changed");
    $(neededRoles).each(function (i, e) {        // using index and element
        if (jQuery.inArray(e, roles) == '-1') {
            console.log("not in array " + e);
        }
    });
}
```

---

jQuery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for `each` method

Answer (score 6):

In loose mode, `this` is **always** an object type, not a primitive type. So the `this` in your callback is a `String`, not a primitive string. `inArray` uses `===` (strict equality) for the check, and a primitive string is not strictly equal to a `String` object.

Several options for you:

#### Use strict mode

In strict mode, `this` can be a primitive, and so your code works (if I add variable declarations; see the "side note" at the end of the answer):

```js
"use strict";
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
finalClick();
function finalClick(){
    var roles=["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
    var neededRoles=["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
    // console.log("test: "+roles[0]);
    var rolecount=0;
    console.log("value changed");
    $(neededRoles).each(function(){
        //console.log("this is this "+this+" "+rolecount+" "+roles[rolecount]);
        if(jQuery.inArray(this, roles)=='-1'){
            console.log("Not in array "+this);
        } else {
            console.log("Found in array "+this);
        }
        //rolecount++;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="console-log"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Use `$.each` instead of `$().each`

Instead of `$(neededRoles).each(...)`, use `$.each(neededRoles, function(index, role)` and use `role`, which will be a string primitive:

```js
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
var console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
finalClick();
function finalClick(){
    var roles=["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
    var neededRoles=["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
    // console.log("test: "+roles[0]);
    var rolecount=0;
    console.log("value changed");
    $.each(neededRoles, function(index, role){
        //console.log("this is this "+this+" "+rolecount+" "+roles[rolecount]);
        if(jQuery.inArray(role, roles) == -1){
            console.log("Not in array " + role);
        } else {
            console.log("Found in array " + role);
        }
        //rolecount++;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="console-log"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Use `Array#forEach` and `Array#indexOf`

Or better yet, use `Array#forEach` and `Array#indexOf`, shimming them on really old browsers that don't have them:

```js
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
var console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};
finalClick();
function finalClick(){
    var roles=["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
    var neededRoles=["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
    // console.log("test: "+roles[0]);
    var rolecount=0;
    console.log("value changed");
    neededRoles.forEach(function(role) {
        if (roles.indexOf(role) == -1) {
            console.log("Not in array " + role);
        } else {
            console.log("Found in array " + role);
        }
        //rolecount++;
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="console-log"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Use `Array#filter`

***If*** your goal is to find missing roles that are required, you can use `Array#filter`:

```js
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
var console = {
  log: function(text) {
    $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
  }
};
finalClick();

function finalClick() {
  var roles = ["President", "Dog", "Treasurer"]
  var neededRoles = ["President", "Secretary", "Treasurer"];
  var missingRoles = neededRoles.filter(function(role) {
    return roles.indexOf(role) == -1;
  });
  console.log("Missing roles: " + missingRoles.join(", "));
}
```

```html
<div id="console-log"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Your original code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you weren't declaring a lot of your variables. I've fixed that in all of the above examples.

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation - the difference between primitives and wrapper objects is easily forgotten.

Comment: You could also just change `this` to `this.toString()`? http://jsfiddle.net/ctn2zv5n/

Comment: @JamieBarker: Hah! Yes, you could. :-)

Comment: @JamieBarker Or `""+this` but do you really want to throw another "hack" into the mix?